# Solve system of equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, equation, equation-solving

I want to solve a system of linear equations in Matlab. The problem is that this system will have a non-unique solution in general ( so the Nullspace is non-trivial) and this system depends on a parameter beta(non-zero!). Hence, I want to have the solution in terms of this parameter. Is MATLAB able to do this? In what way would I need to enter the equations and the parameter and which command would I need to use so that Matlab gives me all solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.   It's not meant to be optimal.   It was tested in octave that has a few
slightly different parsing rules that matlab,  I'm generally good keeping within the shared
syntax of octave and matlab but offering fair warning.

```
    function x=solver(A,y,freeVars)
    %
    %  x=solver(A,y,freeVars)
    % 
    %  Solve system of equations Ax=y for x.
    %  Use elements of freeVars to fill undetermined ranks and produce
    %  a unique solution.
    %
    %  Typically this is of form 
    % 
    %   f_1( t_1 ) * x_1  +  f_2( t_1 ) * x_2 ...  + f_n( t_1 ) * x_n =  y_1
    %
    %   f_1( t_2 ) * x_1  +  f_2( t_2 ) * x_2 ...  + f_n( t_2 ) * x_n =  y_2
    %   .
    %   .
    %   .
    %   f_1( t_m ) * x_1  +  f_2( t_m ) * x_2 ...  + f_n( t_m ) * x_n =  y_m
    %
    %   A= [ f_1( t_1 ) , f_2( t_1 ) , ... f_n( t_1 ) ; 
    %        f_1( t_2 ) , f_2( t_2 ) , ... f_n( t_2 ) ;
    %        ...
    %        f_1( t_m ) , f_2( t_m ) , ... f_n( t_m ) ];
    %
    %  For example a first order linear fit would be
    %  f_1(t) = 1
    %  f_2(t) = t
    %
    %
    %  If the problem is overdetermined this would be a least squares problem 
    %  that is not going to be addressed here.
    %
    %  Assuming fully determined,  one solution would be
    %  Given:Ax=y
    %  [U,S,V]= svd(a)
    %  such that   U*S*V'*x = y
    %                S*V'*x = U'*y
    %  for fully determined case S is invertable.
    %  for less than fully determined case rank(S) < n, 
    %  Let [ S_r | 0 ]  represent the non-zero and zero columns of S.
    %  and [ V_r | 0 ]  represent the columns of V that are used vs. 
    %                   ones multiplied by zeros of S.
    %                [ S_r | 0 ] *  [ V_r |0 ]' * x  = [ U_r | 0 ]' *  y
    %
    %  V_r is in some sense a projection of your x coordinates into rank(S)
    %  subspace that is fully determined.  That portion can be solved
    %  but requires additional parameters to fully determine X.
    % 
    %                 x  =  V * [ inv(S_r)  U_r'  *  y ; alpha ]
    %
    % where alpha's are free parameters filling the extra degrees or freedom.
    %
    % The columns of V that aren't included in V_r are  (were temporarily 
    % temporarily replace by zeros determine which of the x parameters are 
    % impacted by each of the free parameters.
    %
    % Rather than use freevariables as I do here I presume one could set 
    % some x's that were influenced by those freevars to desired values 
    % and backsolve what values of free vars would produce those x's and 
    % then obtain values for the remaining undetermined x's from the computed
    % free vars.   
    %
    %
    [U,S,V]=svd(A)
    s=diag(S);
    %
    % Default rank tolerance taken from help page on rank.
    %
    r=sum(s>max(size(A)) * max(s)* eps )
    %
    % 
    U_r=U(:,1:r)
    S_r=S(1:r,1:r)
    %
    alpha = freeVars(1:(size(y,1)-r) ,1)
    %
    invS_r = diag(diag(S_r).^-1)
    x = V *  [ invS_r * U_r' * y  ; alpha ];
    %
    % aka:
    % x = V_r *  S_r^(-1) * U_r' *y   +   V_n * alpha
```

And simple test cases

```
    % Fully determined case:  
    % mt+b = y   x=[b;m]=[1;2] evaluated at t=0, t=1
    % 
    t=[ 0 ; 1]
    %
    % A = [ 1 , t ]
    %
    A=[ ones(2,1) , t]
    %
    %
    xd=[ 1 ; 2 ]
    y = xd(1) + xd(2)* t

    x=solver(A,y,[1;2;3;4;5])
    xerr=xd-x
    yerr=A*x-y

    % under determined case:  
    % mt+b = y  w/ x=[b;m]=[1;2] evaluated at t=0, t=0
    % 
    t=[ 0 ; 0]
    %
    % A = [ 1 , t ]
    %
    A=[ ones(2,1) , t]
    %
    %
    xd=[ 1 ; 2 ]
    y = xd(1) + xd(2)* t

    x=solver(A,y,[1;2;3;4;5])
    xerr=xd-x
    yerr=A*x-y
```

Answer (score 0):

Maxima [1] can solve equations containing symbolic variables (such as `beta` as you mentioned) and if the solution is not unique, it will introduce dummy variables such that the solution is valid for all values of the dummies. For example:

```
(%i5) solve ([3 * x + beta * y = 5, -6 * x - 2*beta * y = -10], [x, y]);
solve: dependent equations eliminated: (2)
                                %r2 beta - 5
(%o5)                   [[x = - ------------, y = %r2]]
                                     3
```

Here `%r2` is a dummy variable, and the solution works for any value of `%r2`.

However, Maxima's symbolic solver uses a lot of memory, and that might put a relatively low limit on the size of the problem it can handle. How many equations do you have and how many variables? Maybe you can just post the system of equations here.

Sorry that I don't know how to solve this problem in Matlab.

[1] http://maxima.sourceforge.net, http://sourceforge.net/p/maxima